# Unity Android Service

Tags: java, c#, android, unity-game-engine, xamarin.forms

I'm looking for someone to explain to me how to run the Android GPS service on Unity when the app is not open.
I am creating an app where I have to locate the user and find out if they are in a certain location.
Does anyone have a good tutorial on how to start an android service to retrieve the GPS and perform tasks with it while the app is not running?

What the service should do:

1. Start the Android GPS Service
2. Check if the user is near a point of interest
3. Send a notification

Comment: I am not a lawyer but first make sure, if that's legal where your player live. And for question unity has no built-in tool for this. But you can write a java wrapper for this. Because unlike unity, in java you can access all android functionalities. If you have further question for this I suggest you to post question on android and java tags.

Comment: What will not be legal ?

Answer (score 0):

I can't imagine there would be any "legal issues" - Android location services are basically "part of Android".

ANYWAY:

Here is a good article:

[How to Access GPS Location in Unity](https://nosuchstudio.medium.com/how-to-access-gps-location-in-unity-521f1371a7e3),
No Such Dev
Jul 1, 2020

Here is the sample code from the article:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class TestLocationService : MonoBehaviour
{
    IEnumerator LocationCoroutine() {
    // Uncomment if you want to test with Unity Remote
/*#if UNITY_EDITOR
        yield return new WaitWhile(() => !UnityEditor.EditorApplication.isRemoteConnected);
        yield return new WaitForSecondsRealtime(5f);
#endif*/
#if UNITY_EDITOR
        // No permission handling needed in Editor
#elif UNITY_ANDROID
        if (!UnityEngine.Android.Permission.HasUserAuthorizedPermission(UnityEngine.Android.Permission.CoarseLocation)) {
            UnityEngine.Android.Permission.RequestUserPermission(UnityEngine.Android.Permission.CoarseLocation);
        }

        // First, check if user has location service enabled
        if (!UnityEngine.Input.location.isEnabledByUser) {
            // TODO Failure
            Debug.LogFormat("Android and Location not enabled");
            yield break;
        }

#elif UNITY_IOS
        if (!UnityEngine.Input.location.isEnabledByUser) {
            // TODO Failure
            Debug.LogFormat("IOS and Location not enabled");
            yield break;
        }
#endif
        // Start service before querying location
        UnityEngine.Input.location.Start(500f, 500f);
                
        // Wait until service initializes
        int maxWait = 15;
        while (UnityEngine.Input.location.status == LocationServiceStatus.Initializing && maxWait > 0) {
            yield return new WaitForSecondsRealtime(1);
            maxWait--;
        }

        // Editor has a bug which doesn't set the service status to Initializing. So extra wait in Editor.
#if UNITY_EDITOR
        int editorMaxWait = 15;
        while (UnityEngine.Input.location.status == LocationServiceStatus.Stopped && editorMaxWait > 0) {
            yield return new WaitForSecondsRealtime(1);
            editorMaxWait--;
        }
#endif

        // Service didn't initialize in 15 seconds
        if (maxWait < 1) {
            // TODO Failure
            Debug.LogFormat("Timed out");
            yield break;
        }

        // Connection has failed
        if (UnityEngine.Input.location.status != LocationServiceStatus.Running) {
            // TODO Failure
            Debug.LogFormat("Unable to determine device location. Failed with status {0}", UnityEngine.Input.location.status);
            yield break;
        } else {
            Debug.LogFormat("Location service live. status {0}", UnityEngine.Input.location.status);
            // Access granted and location value could be retrieved
            Debug.LogFormat("Location: " 
                + UnityEngine.Input.location.lastData.latitude + " " 
                + UnityEngine.Input.location.lastData.longitude + " " 
                + UnityEngine.Input.location.lastData.altitude + " " 
                + UnityEngine.Input.location.lastData.horizontalAccuracy + " " 
                + UnityEngine.Input.location.lastData.timestamp);

            var _latitude = UnityEngine.Input.location.lastData.latitude;
            var _longitude = UnityEngine.Input.location.lastData.longitude;
            // TODO success do something with location
        }

        // Stop service if there is no need to query location updates continuously
        UnityEngine.Input.location.Stop();
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello,

The thing you don't understand it is that i need this when the application isn't running.

This code run only when the app is open.

Comment: "I am creating an app where I have to locate the user and find out if they are in a certain location". So the app invokes the service, and gets the current location.   ALSO: you need to *DECLARE* that your app wants to use location services in your manifest, so the user can give *PERMISSION* during install.  Perhaps you want to track the user independent of any app?  I don't know if that's technically feasible ... but it's *ABSOLUTELY* a violation of the user's *PRIVACY*.  It's "illegal" in many places ... and *UNETHICAL* everywhere.  If that's your intent - then DON'T.

Comment: How you can know it is illegal? Google know where I go. And I don't store data. I just check if it is near a place.